# How to pass an extra variable to a Qt slot

Tags: c++, qt, signals, signals-slots

I would like to know how to pass a separate variable into a slot.
I cant seem to get it to work. Is there some way around this?

This is my code:

```
QTimer * timer = new QTimer();
connect(timer,SIGNAL(timeout()),this,SLOT(method(MYVARIABLE)));
timer->start(4000);
```

Comment: Since your slot is in the same class as your timer, you can declare `MYVARIABLE` as a class member variable and access it from the `method()` slot - no need to pass it with the signal.

Comment: Please read the documentation before asking questions: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#connect

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you don't want to declare `MYVARIABLE` in your class, but instead to have it tied to this particular signal/slot connection, you can connect the signal to a C++11 lambda using [Qt5's new singal/slot syntax](https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax) and then call your slot with that lambda.

For example you could write:

```
QTimer * timer = new QTimer();
connect(timer, &QTimer::timeout, [=]() {
     method(MYVARIABLE);
});
timer->start(4000);
```

---

Another solution if you can't use C++11 and Qt5 is to use [Qt's Property System](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/properties.html) to attach a variable to your `QTimer*`. This can be done with [`QObject::setProperty()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qobject.html#setProperty).

Then in the slot you could use [`QObject::sender()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#sender) to get your `QTimer*` and read the property back using [`QObject::property()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qobject.html#property).

However, note that it's not a very clean solution, and borderline abuse of the property system.

Comment: "borderline abuse of the property system" I would say that it's in fact a perfect use of the property system. I've done it many times in Qt 4 code, and it leads to the most compact and readable code, so I don't see much wrong with it. It's almost a Qt idiom.

Comment: @KubaOber I've done it too, but I feel a little dirty recommending it just for passing method arguments around :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply I dont have Qt5 can you please give me an example of using setProperty? @tux3

Comment: @user2079139 `timer->setProperty("name", MYVARIABLE)`. It's all in the docs, I left a couple of links in my post.

Answer (score 2):

from http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html

> The rule about whether to include arguments or not in the SIGNAL() and
>   SLOT() macros, if the arguments have default values, is that the
>   signature passed to the SIGNAL() macro must not have fewer arguments
>   than the signature passed to the SLOT() macro.

you can try this

```
QTimer * timer = new QTimer();
connect(timer,SIGNAL(timeout()),this,SLOT(methodSlot()));
timer->start(4000);


methodSlot()
{
    method(MYVARIABLE);
}
```